# If all data were put into memory, what's the fastest way to do a "SELECT ...WHERE ..." thing?

Tags: c, algorithm, memory

If all data were put into memory, which means the media speed is much more faster, what's the fastest way to do a "SELECT .. WHERE .." query (filter data)? So far the options in my mind:

1) b tree like algorithms, but it may still need index and larger space

2) fixed length array, smaller size but may be slower.

So are there any other better ways, if both speed and size are the concerns

Comment: The answer will depend on how much data you are selecting, and what subset of that you are filtering on.  The optimal structure is highly case-specific.

Comment: @cdhowie the size can be within 16GB. Can you give me some clues？

Comment: What's the data? Anything with usable properties? And what sort of thing in the `where` - a range query? An exact match of a single field (always the same field?)?

Comment: Ambitious to try to fit an entire query optimiser into one question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is dependent** on the specific case you have - what operations you need fast, what is the exact size, and more. Some examples:

1. For `AND` queries, a set of sorted lists is usually maintained (a list for each feature). This data structure is called an **[inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index)**, and
   is used often by search engines to get the relevant documents from a
   given query. (Apache Lucene uses this data structure, for example).
2. If **arrays** can be used - and iteration over the data is needed - it is a very efficient approach, since arrays are basically the most [cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) efficient data structure there is. Reading sequentially from an array is much faster in most cases then any other DS, since it gets you the fewest "hit misses", which are often the bottle neck when iterating your data.
3. If your data is strings for example, and you are going to filter according to some string attributes (prefix for example) using a designed data structure for strings, such as a **[trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or a [radix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree)** - might get you the best performance.

**Buttom line**: If you are going to do something custom made in order to enhance performance of the default libraries, you should consider the specific problem details before designing your data structure of choice.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It gives me some hints